# Binding asp.net webform database to if else condition

Tags: asp.net

```
 SqlConnection Conng;
            Conng = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Baglantim"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmdg;
            cmdg = new SqlCommand("Select * From indirimtablosu Where email =" + email.Text + " ", Conng);
            Conng.Open();
            readr = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            SqlDataReader drg = cmdg.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                emailindirim = drg["email"].ToString();
            }
        

            if (email.Text.ToString() == emailindirim.ToString())
            {
                fiyat.Text = drg["indirimliucret"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                
            }
```

Hello, I want to do something like above. If the mail in my discount table and the mail written in the textbox match, the discounted price will be applied, but the current error is that if the discounted price is not defined, it gives an error to the mail, so I currently use it on the appointment page, when I click on the make appointment page, the textbox appears. If the textbox is empty, do not take action before. If the textbox is mailed, how can I say run this code?

I tried the code I wrote above to apply a discount to the e-mail address, if the e-mail written to the textbox and the e-mail in the discount table match, I want the discounted price to be applied.

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow is English only. There are a few language-specific Stack Overflow sites, but I'm afraid Turkish is not one of them, as far as I know.

Comment: [Questions On Stack Overflow Must be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)